# Receive UDP Multicast in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose and hypriotos on a raspberry pi running a node container. I would like to receive udp multicast messages send to 239.255.255.250:1982 in local network. My code is working on other machines outside of docker so I think it's a docker issue.

I already exposed port 1982/udp in the docker file and in the docker-compose file I added "1982:1982" and "239.255.255.250:1982:1982/udp" to ports. I still can't receive anything. Am I missing something?

My concrete plan is to receive advertisement messages from a yeelight. These messages are documented [here](http://www.yeelight.com/download/Yeelight_Inter-Operation_Spec.pdf)

Any help would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can do udp with `-p 1982:1982/udp` I don't believe docker's port forwarding currently supports multicast. You may have better luck if you disable the userland proxy on the daemon (`dockerd --userland-proxy=false ...`), but that's just a guess.

The fast/easy solution, while removing some of the isolation, is to use the host network with `docker run --net=host ...`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the host network now and it works. I had to set the "network_mode" option in the docker-compose file.

Comment: @daniel17903 could you share the config that could make docker container receiving udp broadcast from host?

Comment: The port forwarding solution (without needing to disable the user land proxy on the daemon) works fine for me on Docker 19.03.5 on Linux.

Comment: @rgov curious if that with multicast packets, or normal unicast/udp packets.

Comment: @BMitch The packets are being sent to 192.168.1.255 and received by 192.168.1.100.

Comment: @rgov gotcha, that's subnet broadcast, which is diff from multicast, but still good to know. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that a UDP multicast sender/receiver node.js app in a docker container does **not** work when running a default `docker run` command with no additional options, but running with `--net=host` makes it work.

Comment: @BMitch any idea on how to make it works on Windows machine ? Since Windows does not support the '--net=host'

Comment: @asnawi maybe wsl2? Never tried, just running Linux directly here.