# Cannot connect to a GridDB docker container with multicast network setting

Tags: docker, sql-workbench-j, griddb

I am trying to connect to the GridDB server via sql workbench/j by following this [blog post](https://griddb.net/en/blog/connecting-to-griddb-via-jdbc-with-sqlworkbench-j/).

I setup the GridDB server on a CentOS Docker image, Mac Host and can successfully connect via the sqlwbconsole from within the container, but having problem connecting from the host via the sqlworkbench/j GUI. I am suspecting that the problem is with docker not supporting multicast and found that using --network host should fix the problem (according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422406/receive-udp-multicast-in-docker-container)). But still cannot connect to the database ...

The multicast address is: `jdbc:gs://239.0.0.1:41999/myCluster/public`

Any suggestions how to access in-container's multicast address from the docker host?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried maybe setting the hostname to `localhost` as indicated by this blog: https://griddb.net/en/blog/run-a-griddb-server-in-docker-desktop/